# Maximum height of a huffman coding tree

Tags: c++, binary, binary-tree, huffman-code

What is the maximum height of a tree made with the huffman coding algorithm assuming that all bytes are accepted into it.

I'm curious since I somehow managed to get a path of 9 bits when I tried to compress I file which I generated randomly. Which means that I essentially inflate the size of the file. Though there might be a problem somewhere in the program that I don't know about.

Comment: Maximum height is number of symbols less one. This occurs when one symbol has more occurrences than the sum of the remaining symbols, and so on, recursively.

Comment: Random data cannot be compressed as compression exploits redundancies in the data, and random data has none, so your finding isn't surprising.

Comment: How do you suggest I should handle that situation? Just calculate entropy and then allocate more if there's high entropy?

Comment: Once you have the tree constructed you can calculate the length of the Huffman encoded message. If that length exceeds the length of the uncompressed input then there's no point in encoding the data. You could have an initial flag byte that indicates whether the rest of the file represents a Huffman stream or an uncompressed image.

Comment: If you're trying to compress random data you're not going to get much compression, but it is a good test for the worst-case scenario.

Comment: Alright, thanks, out of curiousity how does e.g. 7z or tar etc handle these things? They probably have better algorithms for it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "all bytes" you mean all 256 possible byte values as your set of symbols, the answer is that the maximum depth, and so the length of the longest code, is 255.

To get this though requires very large numbers for the frequencies of the symbols. The sequence that does this with the smallest total count are the Lucas numbers, with the zeroth Lucas number of 2 broken into two 1's. So:

```
1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123, 199, ...
```

where the terms starting with 4 are the sum of the previous two terms, just like the Fibonacci sequence. The last term in that sequence for 256 symbols is:

```
121020968315000050139390193037122554865361969834971243
```

About 10<sup>53</sup>.

As for your random data of all possible bytes, in general you can't compress it. However if you got one code of 9 bits in length, then that means the code is at least as good as assigning 8 bits to all of the symbols. So you did not inflate the file, but rather left it the same size or reduced it by a bit or more. However that's not taking into account the fact that you have to also send the code itself so that the decoder on the other end can decode. That will more than kill any tiny bit of compression you got.